# how fetch api knows relative url?

Tags: javascript, url, fetch

static javascript files are downloaded from server to client browser and runs there right?

if I have a `.js` file with contents below,

```js
fetch("/api/users")
```

I believe this resolves to full URL of its server's domain or IP address.
(such as `https://my.server.com/api/users`)

But how does this script knows that itself came from host `my.server.com` and therefore should prefix with that host name?

I mean, scripts are just independent files and does not know about environment it is running at.

Comment: "this resolves to full URL of its server's domain or IP address." If you mean the ones of the js file, then no, for `fetch` the full URL is computed from the document's or environment's baseURL, not from the current script. Maybe you were confusing with `import`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how does this script knows that itself came from host my.server.com and therefore should prefix with that host name?

It's part of the [specification of the `fetch` API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-request), specifically:

> 3. Let baseURL be this’s relevant settings object’s API base URL.

Which itself links off to various other places defining 3 different things specifying those.

In short, it's not anything the scripts themselves that are running are doing - it's the implementation of `fetch` that's doing it, whether that's provided by the browser, or a serverside runtime such as Node etc.